# I have two separate narrators, how do I turn it off?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, narrator

A few months ago my sister did something to my laptop (though she claims she didn't) and ever since then I have this weird male voice that narrates every single little thing from my details and what I type on the login page (including my password) to where my cursor goes etc. I have tried turning it off via Ease of Access centre but that only shows the actual narrator which is a female voice and can be turned on and off without problem.

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and the male narrator voicce seemed to have disappeared until today when I accidentally pressed 'ctrl+alt+n' and it came back. I've tried turning it off by redoing the keyboard shortcut and unticking all the boxes in ease of access but nothing works!

Please please please help, I'm being forced to keep my laptop on mute at all times just so it won't speak!

Comment: Are you sure you pressed that exact keyboard shortcut? I can't find anything online about it. Also, have you tried rebooting your computer? Also could you edit your answer with a link to a screenshot of Task Manager 'details' tab?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I have managed to sort it out! It was something to do with 'NVDA' (I don't even know what that is) lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/) installed on your computer. The start shortcut for it is indeed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, and by default it uses a male narrator.

Just uninstall it, and the annoying voice should disappear.

Comment: oldmud0 - YOU ARE A LIFESAVER thank you so much, as soon as I uninstalled it the voice disappeared! I didn't even know I had NVDA installed in the first place but I searched my computer and it came up. I can't thank you enough, it was really doing my head in -.-